# Reprojection from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:31468 in deegree

Tags: coordinate-system, grids-graticules, deegree

I have source data in EPSG:3857 that is shifted approximately 20 KM north when reprojected to EPSG:31468 in deegree version 3.4.17 and I am trying to determine the cause.

I am wondering if deegree may be missing the grid required to do the transformation? I would like to add the the [de_adv_BETA2007](https://cdn.proj.org/de_adv_BETA2007.tif) grid to deegree. The [beta2007](https://github.com/wetransform/kelvin/blob/master/deegree-core/deegree-core-cs/src/main/resources/org/deegree/cs/persistence/deegree/d3/config/ntv2/beta2007.gsb) grid currently available in deegree appears to be slightly offset from the de_adv_BETA2007?:

[image: QGIS screenshot of grid shift]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to add this to deegree for testing, or other insights on this problem?

Comment: The newest version seems to be 3.4.33 https://www.deegree.org/download, I would first have a new try with that. I suppose that you use QGIS for showing the vectors that you have transformed first with deegree, right?

Comment: Hi @user30184,

My workflow is to publish source data in EPSG:3857 in deegree and request it from the WFS in EPSG:31468. In QGIS the EPSG:31468 file displays shifted. 

It kind of looks like datum shift. I checked and QGIS runs a transformation pipeline using `+proj=hgridshift +grids=de_adv_BETA2007.tif` so I am trying to determine if the same parameters are used in deegree.

Comment: I suggest to contact deegree developers directly https://www.deegree.org/community/, I do not know if they follow this site regularly. Of course deegree is open source so you can also read the source code if you wish. Deegree is using their own coordinate transformation library, but because the project is mostly German I would guess that they have good support for German GK zones.

Comment: 20 km is much more than is usual for a datum/geoCRS offset--usually it's a few hundred meters at most. Is there any chance of a mix-up between 3857 and 3395? 3395 uses an ellipsoidal Mercator projection while 3857 uses a spherical Mercator. That can lead to a north-south offset of kilometers.

Comment: @mkennedy I'm not sure that's the issue. I've started unit testing, and trying to understand the transformation chain in deegree. The first transfo has nested 1st and 2nd tranfos which look like 3857 to 4978 to 4314. The second transfo looks like 4314 to 31468. In QGIS, the operation is: ```+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +step +inv +proj=hgridshift +grids=de_adv_BETA2007.tif +step +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel```.

Comment: OH. Try taking out the +ellps=WGS84 in the first step. It *might* be overriding the proj=webmerc option which should use a sphere to unproject to wgs84.

Comment: @mkennedy Sorry for not being more clear. The QGIS operation is working as expected. I am using it for comparison purposes.

Comment: Sorry! My fault.